# Web app that lists all the cheapest sellers of a product matching a given set of options, in the UK

Tags: web-apps, shopping

I'm based in the UK. I'm in the market for a new phone, and I'd like to be able to see a list of the cheapest places for a phone with options that I specify.

For example, if I'm after a sim-free, dual-sim Google Pixel in white with 128GB of space, I'd like to be able to input those options and return only results for products matching them, sorted by price from lowest to highest.

The only solutions that I can currently find appear not to support the explicit specifying of options, requiring a user to wade through lots of redundant results, or else pull results only from Amazon.co.uk, without searching the sites of retailers like Curry's or Argos, which can sometimes be cheaper.

Are there any websites like this? If there aren't... could someone please make one?

Comment: You list some big UK box shops. Are you open to foreign sites, like AliExpress?

Comment: @Mawk Additional sites would be a bonus, but I'd expect all the main local options to be scraped as minimum.

Comment: I understand (although personally, I now buy all of electronics direct from China, where they are manufactured. I would certainly never pay Currys prices :-) But this is a great question ,and I hope to see an answer. I guess it should search eBay too?

Comment: @Mawg If the site in question could successfully scrape prices from eBay while making sure it matched all of the criteria, then that would definitely be impressive, but it seems like too much to ask given that there's apparently no site that even searches just the local stores, which will tend to have the one matching product variant instead of thousands.

Comment: @Mawg Out of curiosity, when you say you buy directly from China do you do this because it's cheaper? And if you do, do you buy from Aliexpress or from other specific sites?

Comment: I buy because it is ***much*** cheaper. I mainly buy on AliExpress. I recently found an article on alternatives to AliExpress , with reviews, and thought that I might try some, just small purchases at first.  Forty percent of everything manufactured on earth  is made in China, so why not go to the source. Plus, they have subsidized postage, so shipping  costs little, or is free.

Comment: @Mawg I assume you're from the UK? It seems like a promising idea, but what's the situation with import/sales taxes?

Comment: I am currently based in the UK, but I don’t know how much longer.  I only buy electronics, because I know what I am doing with those. And ties. Lots and lot sand lots of ties. On eBay I can buy a tie, with matching handkerchief and cufflinks for £2 or £3, including postage, of surprisingly good quality – and someone makes a profit on that somehow! I don’t think that I would by other clothes, what if they don’t fit? Hmm, I wonder if I can find cheap books from China…

Comment: I can't recall paying customs duty. I suppose it is possible, but unlikely.  Even with customs, I believe you would still be better off. But I certainly didn't pay any on my last two ‘phones which both came to UK.

Comment: Very interesting. Budget is definitely an issue, so it sounds like an option once I've figured out what phone I'm after and with which options. Books are also something to look out for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website that comes close to what you are looking for is [pricespy.co.uk](https://pricespy.co.uk). It allows you to specify the manufacturer, the color, the product name.

The only problem I can find is in case two products are named quite the same such as Google Pixel 3 and Google Pixel 3 XL. If you specify the product name as Google Pixel 3, it will include Google Pixel 3 XL as well.

There are tons of filters to go through so you might be able to narrow it down further to just Google Pixel 3, white, 128GB.

[image]

Comment: I'd come across this site but didn't realise the advanced options can only be accessed when browsing, not searching - weird way to have it. This is a great find, and currently the best answer. The main failing of it is that, for some reason, it doesn't seem to include Marketplace sellers/prices, even when they're listed as New condition. Something that could both include Marketplace products in New condition by default, as well as Used ones if specified, would be the perfect solution.